# Why can not connect internet from centos on virtualbox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I lost whole day but still can not fix this internet connection problems.

I appriciate any suggestions.

[image: Configured Bridged Adapter]

[image]

Comment: This is not a question about programming, it is about server administration.

Answer (score 1):

Click on `Cable Connected` in order to plug the virtual cable in.

Comment: It run well. Thanks for your support